# Данные не записываются с формы в mysql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, html-form

```
<html>

<title>form</title>

<h1>Registration form</h1>

<form action="form.php" method="POST"> 
   
    <label for="name">name: </label>
    <input type="name" id="name" name="name">

    <label for="text">bio: </label>
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text">

    <label for="date">date: </label>
    <input type="date"  id="date" name="date">

    <label for="email">email: </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">

    <label for="password">password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">

    <button>Send</button>

</form>

</html>

//php code starts

<?php

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root', 'root', 'testmysql');

$new_user = $_POST ["name"];
$new_text = $_POST ["text"];
$new_date = $_POST["date"];
$new_email = $_POST["email"];
$new_password = $_POST["password"];



if($mysql->connect_error){
    echo "Error number: ".$mysql->connect_errno.'<br>';
    echo "Error: ".$mysql->connect_error;
}
else {
    echo "connection succesfull";
}
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `for_test`(`name`, `bio`, `date`, `email`,`password`)VALUES('$new_user', '$new_text','$new_date', '$new_email', '$new_password')");
?>
```

Comment: Если что я проверял переменные на наличие данных с формы и в базе данных по порядку написаны поля

Comment: Желательно бы проверить результат выполнения **mysql->query** И в случае ошибки выводить эту ошибку, тоже желательно. Это может сильно помочь вам в отладке.

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (Я не понял ошибку когда я вывожу у меня выводит 5 значений формы) В чем может быть проблема есть идеи?

Comment: Когда убрал все связанное с date код заработал но я так и не понял в чем была проблема

Comment: Ну может у вас  значениях где то были кавычки и запятые. Если так подставлять переменные как вы можно не только получать совершенно неожиданные ошибки, но и подвергнуться взлому сайта через sql-инъекции. ВСЕГДА используйте привязку переменных, а не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в запрос. https://php.ru/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.html

Comment: У вас в коде пропущена запятая. Вот здесь **'$new_date' '$new_email'**

Answer (score 0):

В запросе пропущена запятая

```
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `for_test`(`name`, `bio`, `date`, `email`,`password`)
VALUES('$new_user', '$new_text','$new_date' '$new_email', '$new_password')");
```

между '$new_date' и '$new_email'

Поэтому и рекомендется не писать в коде длинные строки - так сложнее находить в них ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО, 
html date input не совпадает (m-d-y) с mysql 
нужно до внесение в базу данных изменить

пример:

```
$new_dob = date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["dateofbirth"]));
```